# Getting Array to string conversion error in PHP code

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having issues with this php code. The getDatabase() function usually returns a string but sometime it returns an array. I tried to correct this using lines 3 through 5 but this has not corrected it, as it still produces the " Array to string conversion error" on the "echo $compoundId" line.

```
$compoundIdt= getDatabase("Select compound_id from compound where dsrt_id = '" . $localId[0] . ".;");
            //debug for multiples
            if (is_array($compoundIdt) ){
                $compoundId= array_slice($compoundId,0,1);
            }
            echo $compoundId;//produces error
```

Comment: `$compoundId` is an array and you are `echo`ing it.

Comment: use `print_r($compoundId);` instead of `echo $compoundId;`